# Erro no método $.post

Tags: jquery

A pagina index.html contém:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>teste</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="teste.php"><img id="adicionar" src="aceitar.jpg" alt="aceitar" style="height: 75px"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

O script.js contém:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#adicionar").click(function(){
        alert ("A imagem foi clicada");
        $.post( "teste.php", {name: "John"} );
    });
});
```

E por fim teste.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    echo $name;
} else {
    echo "O método POST falhou!";
}
?>
```

Qual o erro neste exemplo básico do método $.post?

Comment: Nos diga você, algum erro no console?

Comment: O que você esperava que acontecesse e o que aconteceu de fato? Você nem tratou a resposta da requisição POST, então como concluiu que a mesma não funciona? Deu erro?

Comment: Eu esperava que o método post mandasse a variável 'name' com valor 'John' para página teste.php, que eu recuperasse com a variável global $_POST e imprimisse o valor da váriavel. Em vez disso, a variável 'name' não consta na variável global, sendo imprimido o else da condicional if.

Comment: Como você verificou isso?

Comment: _"imprimisse o valor da váriavel"_ podes explicar melhor essa frase? E, como o @AndersonCarlosWoss referiu, falta-te passar `function(){}` ao `$.post`

Comment: Eu esperava que a condicional if fosse ao echo $name e entrou o echo "O método post falhou".  Eu não coloquei nenhuma function no ajax porque o meu interesse é realizar funções php-banco de dados com a variável que eu quero passar pelo $.post

Comment: Mas como vês que entra no `O método post falhou`? Com ajax se não escutas a resposta não acontece nada na página, ou seja o PHP não corre na página que está no browser...

Comment: Eu vejo que falhou porque não existe a variável que o método deveria criar. Ao invocar o método, eu redireciono para a url que deveria receber os dados do post.